# AJAX: Update div class after POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

What I'm trying to do here, is after I double click a row, that points to the function as below..., nothing seems to update the div class.

```
function book(id)
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_servlet.php?action=book",
        data: id,
        success: function(response)
        {
          if(response == 'success')
          {
            $("#ajax_resp").html("<div class='alert alert-success alert-dismissible' role='alert'><button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert'><span aria-hidden='true'>&times;</span><span class='sr-only'>Close</span></button><strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself youre not looking too good.</div>");
          }
          else
          {
            $("#ajax_resp").html("");
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

And here is the div class...

```
<div class="ajax_resp"></div>
```

The response is being returned "success", but the `#ajax_resp` is not being updated with the function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You use `ID` selector in jQuery and have `class` in HTML. So should be:

```
$(".ajax_resp").html...
   ^
```

Comment: @Kyle try to replace `class` in your html to `id` and change `.` in selector to `#`